# SQLite class to manage recipes for an Android application

Tags: java, beginner, android, sqlite

I have a class file that would be used to connect and execute queries into the database. The only thing I am confused about is this: do you really need to drop tables and re-create them everytime you run the application? Or does this depend on your coding or class file? I followed a tutorial on the Internet and kind of recycled the class file it provided to cope with my needs.

Do give me suggestions to better my class file if needed. I am a bit new to Java/Android and do not know the best way to do these, though I would love to learn how.

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBConnect {

        int id = 0;
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_IP = "saved_ip_address";
        private static final String TAG = "DBConnect";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MenuBook";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "ipaddress";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "menudb";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_3 = "recipelist";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE ipaddress (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                                 "saved_ip_address text not null " +
                                 "); "+
            "CREATE TABLE menudb (menu_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL, " +
                                 "menu_name longtext, " +
                                 "menu_price double DEFAULT NULL, " +
                                 "menu_description longtext, " +
                                 "menu_category text, " +
                                 "menu_status text, " +
                                 "PRIMARY KEY (menu_ID) " +
                                 "); "+
            "CREATE TABLE recipelist (recipe_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                 "menu_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, " +
                                 "stock_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, " +
                                 "recipe_quantity double DEFAULT NULL, " +
                                 "PRIMARY KEY (recipe_ID) " +
                                 ");" ;

        private final Context context;

        private static DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private static SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBConnect(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context)
            {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
            {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                                  int newVersion)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion
                      + " to "
                      + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ipaddress");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS menudb");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recipelist");
                onCreate(db);
            }

        }

        //---opens the database---
        public DBConnect open() throws SQLException
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        //---closes the database---
        public void close()
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }

        //---insert a title into the database---
        public long insertIPAddress(String ipaddress)
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_IP, ipaddress);
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);
        }


}
```

I haven't finished this class file yet since I am still looking for more codes that I could use thus there are only 3 methods available here as of now. I am using it on an `onClick` event on one activity like this.

```
ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress);
ip = ipaddress.getText().toString();
db.open();
db.insertIPAddress(ip);
db.close();
```

Comment: Heck no, you don't need to be constantly creating/dropping the tables.  For one, thing, that's terribly 'expensive'.  Also, what happens when users come back to the app - they'd complain about missing data!  There should be a way to do 'one time setup', either as part of the android install process, or simply the first time your app runs.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` are called by the Android framework only when necessary, so this code is not constantly creating/dropping tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using one instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` across your application (which you should be doing), you should never need to call `close` on it or the `SQLiteDatabase` object.

Why do you need the `DBConnect` class? See [this answer for another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/36230/8891) for a proper thread-safe `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass. If you follow that example, this would be its usage:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
dbHelper.insertIPAddress(ipAddr);
```