# Android SQLite Database management

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'd like some opinions about my approach at using SQLite databases in android. Everything seems to work very well, but there may be something wrong that I hadn't noticed.

I don't like working with create/alter table statements in code, so I prefer creating my database with some SQLite client out there and putting it in assets folder.  I use some logic to decide when the database must be replaced and which records need to be kept, then use this code in a class called DbManager:

```
private static SQLiteDatabase _db = null;

public static Object lock = new Object();

private static SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
    if (_db == null) {
        _db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    return _db;
}


//this is the approach used for insert operations, but is the same for update, delete etc
public static boolean insert(String tableName, ContentValues values) {
    try {
        return getDB().insert(tableName, null, values) >= 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogHelper.WriteLogError("error in DB_manager.insert function", e);
        return false;
    }
}

public static synchronized void beginTransaction(String who) {
    LogHelper.WriteLogDebug("starting transaction by " + (who == null ? "null" : who));
    try {
        //in this way if a transaction is still executing it waits untill the previus ends.
        //obviously every time i call DbManager.beginTransaction the call at DbManager.endTransaction is in the finally statment
            if (_db.inTransaction()) {
                LogHelper.WriteLogInfo("DB IS IN TRANSACTION");
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }
            getDB().beginTransactionWithListener(new SQLiteTransactionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRollback() {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                         LogHelper.WriteLogInfo("onRollback listener invoked");
                         lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCommit() {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        LogHelper.WriteLogInfo("onCommit listener invoked");
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                    public void onBegin() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogHelper.WriteLogError("error calling begin transaction by " + (who == null ? "null" : who), e);
            }
        }

        public static void endTransaction(boolean commitChanges, String who) {
            LogHelper.WriteLogDebug("ending transaction by " + (who == null ? "null" : who));
            try {
                if (commitChanges)
                    getDB().setTransactionSuccessful();
                getDB().endTransaction();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogHelper.WriteLogError("error calling end transaction by " + (who == null ? "null" : who), e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

The code looks fine to me but it is a bit odd because [the official docs recommend creating a `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) to handle database interaction. And if you use one `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance across your application, it will be thread-safe so there's no need to add your own synchronization logic:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "location_scout.db";
  private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

  // Singleton pattern
  private static DatabaseHelper instance;
  public synchronized static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
      if(instance == null) {
          instance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
      }
      return instance;
  }

  private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the docs? Also, is it really necessary to use it as singleton?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: It's not _required_ but it's the easiest way to make it thread-safe and not run into memory leak issues. More info: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Comment: Damn yes! I use SQLight a lot on Android.  But somehow I missed this... Thanks for this hint.